# Solve for $p(x-1) = x+1$ in $\mathbb C[x]/(x^3-x^2)$ (or give software to help)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory

I'm wondering if there exists any reasonable software for doing computations with (polynomial) rings, similar to GAP for groups. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2744065/computing-generators-of-polynomial-rings-software-algorithm) question seems to have asked for something similar, but it went unanswered.

> The particular problem that I need solving, if anyone can do it independently of the above request, is figuring out which polynomials $p$ makes the equation $p(x-1) = x+1$ true in $R = \mathbb C[x]/(x^3-x^2)$.

I believe $p$ exists by the following reasoning: The only prime ideals of $R$ are $(x)$ and $(x-1)$ (in particular, these are the prime ideals of $\mathbb C[x]$ containing $x^3 - x^2$). We have that $(x+1)(x-1)x^2 = x^4 - x^2 = 0$, so $x+1$ is a zero-divisor, so it isn't a unit, so it's in one of the prime ideals. It's not in $(x)$ since it's clear that there are no polynomials with non-zero constant terms in this ideal. Thus $x+1 \in (x-1)$.

Comment: [Sage](https://www.sagemath.org/) has features for solving polynomial equations, but I've never tried to solve this kind of problem. It might be worth checking their (extensive) [documentation](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/constructions/index.html) though! Good luck ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. The element $x+1$ is a unit, where $x-1$ is not (you showed that $x-1$ is a prime element which cannot be a unit). To show $(1+x)p = 1$ mod $(x^2-x^3)$, take $p = 1 - x + \frac12x^2$. We have
$$
(1+x)(1 - x + \frac12x^2) = 1 - x + \frac12x^2 + x - x^2 + \frac12x^3 = 1
$$
mod $(x^2-x^3)$ since $\frac12x^3 = \frac12x^2$ in $R$.

In your calculation $(x+1)(x-1)x^2 = x^4 - x^2 = 0$, notice that $(x-1)x^2 = x^3-x^2$ is already zero in $R$.

Comment: Agh. That was very silly of me, thank you

Comment: Can I ask how you came up with $p$? I spent some time blindly plugging in monic integer polynomials to check if $x+1$ was a unit before I found my "counterexample", and I feel like I would never have found this..

Comment: I used a very low-tech approach. Any element in $R$ can be expressed with a polynomial of degree at most $2$. So start with $p = 1 +bx +c x^2$, and solve the equations. However, I used the fact there are only two maximal ideal $xR$ and $(x-1)R$ to see that $1+x$ is a unit.

Comment: @fish You can do extended Euclidean algorithm on $\mathbb C[x]$ (or any $K[x]$ for field $K$). The first division step immediately give you
$$
x^3 - x^2 = (x^2-2x+2)(x+1) -2 \implies (x^2-2x+2)(x+1) \equiv 2 \in \mathbb C[x]/(x^3-x^2)
$$
For your original problem you are solving for
$$
p (x - 1) + q (x^3 - x^2) = x + 1
$$
in $\mathbb C[x]$ which becomes
$$
(p+1)(x-1) + qx^2(x-1) = 2 \implies (p+1+qx^2)(x-1) = 2
$$
So the $x-1$ common factor makes it impossible (RHS will be constant or a GCD). Software like Sage or Mathematica should have commands for doing the extended GCD.

Comment: Very illuminative, thank you.